# How to execute content updates in transaction using Umbraco 7?

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I would like to move a content node and change some properties. But it should be done in a transaction. The operations are done with PetaPoco Framework and it support transactions.
Looking for the proper way to achieve transactional content updates.

I just wrote the following imaginary code to demonstrate what I'd like to achieve. I need something like this:

```
using (var transaction = DatabaseContext.Database.GetTransaction())
{
    var content = Services.ContentService.GetById(model.Id);
    Services.ContentService.Move(content, parentId);
    content.SetValue("prop", "value");
    Services.ContentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(content);
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: FYI: the code example looks surprisingly close to the syntax we're actually using for scopes so your imaginary code should only require minimal changes when scopes are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's unfortunately no way to do this right now, as the services do not support transactions/scopes.

It will however be possible to do this in the future, as we're currently implementing transactions (scopes) for internal use in the service layer in v. 7.6. I am not sure when it will be possible to use this outside of the Core namespace as we still have some testing to do, but it will hopefully be soon.

Comment: Thank you, Claus.